# How to generate a UUID compliant with RFC4122?

Tags: python, uuid, rfc4122

I am trying to create a UUID that follows the RFC4122 requirements. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.RFC_4122) for UUID v5 states:

> `uuid.uuid5(namespace, name)`
> Generate a UUID based on the SHA-1 hash of a namespace identifier (which is a UUID) and a name (which is a string).

and

> `uuid.RFC_4122`
> Specifies the UUID layout given in RFC 4122.

I do not understand what the "name" in the explanation above is:

```
>>> import uuid
>>> uuid.uuid5(uuid.RFC_4122, 'hello') 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python310\lib\uuid.py", line 720, in uuid5
    hash = sha1(namespace.bytes + bytes(name, "utf-8")).digest()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'bytes'
```

It is surprisingly difficult to find an example of the generation of this UUID (I could not find any, anywhere).

Comment: The meaning of name is defined by the namespace. It is documented for each of the `NAMESPACE_*` constants in the module.

Answer (score 2):

The `uuid` module is almost always following RFC 4122. That is, if you use one of the `uuidx` functions, it should give an RFC 4122 UUID. `uuid.RFC_4122` is not a namespace; it's just a string that says `'specified in RFC 4122'`. The namespaces are:

- [`NAMESPACE_DNS`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS)
- [`NAMESPACE_URL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.NAMESPACE_URL)
- [`NAMESPACE_OID`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.NAMESPACE_OID)
- [`NAMESPACE_X500`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.NAMESPACE_X500)

To generate an RFC 4122 UUID, use one of these functions:

- [`uuid1`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid1)
  Generate a UUID from the time and hostname.
- [`uuid3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid3)
  Generate a UUID from an MD5 hash of one of the namespaces above and a name.
- **Preferred:** [`uuid4`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid4)
  Generate a random UUID.
- [`uuid5`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid3)
  Generate a UUID from an SHA1 hash of one of the namespaces above and a name.

It's preferred to use `uuid.uuid4()`, because it's actually random.

You can actually check that a UUID uses RFC 4122:

```py
In [1]: import uuid

In [2]: my_UUID = uuid.uuid4()

In [3]: my_UUID.variant
Out[3]: 'specified in RFC 4122'

In [4]: my_UUID
Out[4]: UUID('2721ffc3-f8a9-417e-a124-af057434a3af')
```

Note: for obvious reasons, you won't get the same UUID as me.